# Rails 4--Chosen menu style not rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-chosen

I'm using Rails 4, trying to get Chosen to work but it does not render, instead the standard multi select menu displays. I have done everything in the railscast here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields-revised?autoplay=true

but Chosen does not work. Any advice or alterations? The files are below:

Gemfile:

```
gem 'chosen-rails', '1.0.1'
gem 'compass-rails', github: 'Compass/compass-rails'
```

_field.html.erb  :

```
<%= f.label :category_ids, "Restaurant Categories" %>
<%= f.collection_select :category_ids, Category.all, :id, :name, {}, {multiple: true} %>
```

application.js  :

```
//= require jquery
//= require chosen-jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

application.css:

```
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require chosen
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

users.js.coffee:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#category_ids').chosen()
```

Comment: Is the jQuery loading properly when you view the source? And do you get an error message in the console?

Comment: Justin,  viewing the source I do not believe jQuery is loading is loading, given the menu still functions but not as Chosen wants it to. In the video he notes when editing the jQuery, to "make sure the DOM has loaded", what does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I would try is to load `jquery-ujs` before `chosen-rails` in your `application.js`

So your `application.js` would look like

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require chosen-jquery
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Hopefully this helps fix your problem

Comment: I just did it and reset the server, did not work. Is there something about Rails 4 that would prevent this gem from working? Anything?

Answer (score 0):

I've just faced the same issue. Solved it this way:

1. Added **jquery-turbolinks** gem via:

   `gem 'jquery-turbolinks'`
2. Updated application.js as stated in **jquery-turbolinks** gem:

> ```
>   //= require jquery
>   //= require jquery.turbolinks
>   //= require jquery_ujs
>   //
>   // ... your other scripts here ...
>   //
>   //= require turbolinks
> ```

I hope you find this useful.